# Specify which fingerprint utility to use for sudo

Tags: command-line, sudo, fingerprint-reader

I've set up my fingerprint reader and made fingerprint authentication possible for terminal `sudo` commands. Yay so far.

However, I have a GUI utility that requires sudo permissions. The utility specifies the `SUDO_ASKPASS` environment variable to delegate the password input to a GUI tool (Zenity). However, since `sudo` now first asks for a fingerprint, this no longer works correctly.

Is there another environment variable for sudo or for pam with which I can specify which utility to run when asking for fingerprint authentication?